# Google Cloud Storage from another project for the Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-storage

I have an application on Flutter that uses Firebase for authorization. Now I need to connect my Flutter app to Google Cloud Storage of another project. How do I do this correctly and securely?

Comment: You can create a service account in the project and export its JSON key file that you can use to authenticate your Flutter app and grant it permission to access the Google Cloud Storage bucket of the other project.

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I tried to do just that today, and it looks way too hard to connect to google api in flutter web to use that service account.. Could you elaborate on your comment, please?

For now it seems too hard and forces you to re-create the buckets and use new ones via firebase..

Comment: @vladli check an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sathi's comment was very helpful. You just create a service account and get its creds from json. Then you register the storage with the StorageApi.

1. Create service account using gcloud console: IAM & Admin -> Service Accounts -> Create Service Account
2. Create a key for new service account: Service Accounts -> Actions (for your account) -> Manage Keys -> Add Key
3. Initialize StorageApi in your app:

Example with DI using GetIt:

```
Future<void> _registerStorageApi() async {
  final accountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
    "type": "YOUR_TYPE",
    "private_key_id": "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_ID",
    "private_key": "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY",
    "client_email": "YOUR_CLIENT_EMAIL",
    "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
  });

  final scopes = [StorageApi.devstorageReadWriteScope];
  final authClient = await clientViaServiceAccount(accountCredentials, scopes);
  sl.registerLazySingleton<StorageApi>(() => StorageApi(authClient));
}
```

then just call this method in your inject method:

```
await _registerStorageApi();
```

Please note that you need to set the Storage Admin role for service account.